# Hi, I to want to convert my html code to pdf file (react). I tried using jspdf and html2canvas, but they convert html>image>pdf, any other solutions?

Tags: html, reactjs, pdf, blob

I  to want to convert my html code to pdf file (react). I tried using jspdf and html2canvas, but they convert html data to image and then to pdf, is there a way to convert html code in react to pdf where all the content is selectable. I tried multiple ways such as html2psf, phantomjs, etc. Nothing worked.

I also want to store my pdf file in blob data.

Comment: Jspdf should work. That's what I use personally. Add a code example for us to check if there are any errors. Also, Puppeteer should work too.

Comment: Jspdf works well, its working right now but the issue is it converts code to image and then to pdf. We can not select the data in the pdf. Any other solutions ?

Comment: Then you're not using the correct method from the jspdf api. Are you using this: https://artskydj.github.io/jsPDF/docs/module-html.html ?

Comment: I am using a combination of jspdf and html2canvas as just jspdf doesn't apply any css style. It just prints the data as it is how it looks in browser but the styles are not applied while generating the pdf.

Comment: Unhandled Promise Rejection! Reason=Error: Unknown source type. 

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unknown source type at Promise.<anonymous> (jspdf.min.js:118)

Getting this error, any idea?